# Hive statistics

Tags: statistics, hive

I am trying to compute statistics on ORC File, but I am unable see any changes in PART_COL_STATS as well on using

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.reliable=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
```

to get max value of a column it is running full Map reduce on column ..
what I want to use is max value stored in meta store, but I am unable to catch these statistics.

My **table desc** is:

```
load_inst_id int
src_filename string
server_date date
```

My **analyze query** is:

```
analyze table mytable partition(server_date=’2013-11-30′) compute statistics for columns load_inst_id;
```

I am always getting 0 as loadinstant id, I have to turn off my `hive.compute.query.using.stats` to get correct result(through map reduce max(load_inst_id))